# Why is the Cauchy root the sharpest possible absolute bound?

Tags: polynomials, roots, intuition, upper-lower-bounds

Consider the Cauchy bound for the roots of a complex polynomial $f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\cdots + a_0$, which states that the moduli of all zeros of $f$ are less or equal to the unique positive root of the Cauchy polynomial $$g(x) = |a_n|x^n - |a_{n-1}|x^{n-1} - \cdots - |a_0|.$$
The fact that $g(x)$ has a unique positive root follows immediately from Descartes rule of signs.

According to my professor this bound is supposed to be the sharpest possible bound for the moduli of the zeros of a polynomial, if only the moduli of the coefficients are known. He refused to give an explanation because, in his words, it would be obvious to see for myself, but it isn't.

I am not looking for a rigorous proof, but can anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: I don't think that is the case. According to Wikipedia, Lagrange's bound is sometimes sharper than the Cauchy bound. There are also numerous papers providing refinements of the Cauchy bound, eg, [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325951702_A_refinement_of_cauchy%27s_bound_for_the_moduli_of_zeros_of_a_polynomial) and [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43678942).

Comment: There are a lot of root bounds attributed to Cauchy, the bounds in the papers you linked and on wikipedia (if you are referring to this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots) are not the one I mentioned above.
The bound above has the downside of being computationally expensive to determine, but in my tests so far it has proven to be sharper than any other bound I implemented (including bounds due to Ballieu, Kojima, Fujiwara, Walsh, and some more).